# Page redirection causing request bean creation twice

Tags: java, jsf

When the users attempt login to my application after supplying credentials & pressing the commandButton(whose `action` attribute redirects user to a relevant page after verification), my app is instantiating a `@RequestScoped` bean when the `action` attribute's method is executed. Now after the redirection is done, after successful login, this bean is again needed on the redirected page. But this bean was destroyed, so it is required to be re-created.

Is this just normal ? I expect the bean to be there for the complete request as redirection was just a part of the request.

Anyways if this is normal for a request bean what is the alternative for me to survive this complete request but no longer after that.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for your long explanation. I managed to solve this issue by  removing altogether the need for request bean to survive these two requests & just be created during the 2nd request when it was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is normal, the life of request scoped bean is from request - response,

if you do redirect it would be

> request - response(instruction to make a new GET) - request - response( serving a new page)

Comment: So are there any alternatives/ workarounds that would allow me to do what I am needing ?

Comment: SessionScoped , or if you are redirecting to the same view then ViewScope